# Both main program and dlopen'ed library need different versions of libsqlite3.so

Tags: python, dynamic-linking, dlopen

I have a main program that depends on `libsqlite3.so`. By running it with `LD_DEBUG=libs ./my_executable`, I observe the following (I edited the search paths to look simpler):

```
    386600:     find library=libsqlite3.so.0 [0]; searching
    386600:      search path=/a:/b:/c:/d:/e              (RPATH from file /home/me/my_executable)
    386600:       trying file=/a/libsqlite3.so.0
    386600:       trying file=/b/libsqlite3.so.0
    386600:       trying file=/c/libsqlite3.so.0
    386600:       trying file=/d/libsqlite3.so.0
    386600:       trying file=/e/libsqlite3.so.0
```

So far so good, the runtime linker correctly uses the `RPATH` from `my_executable` to eventually find `libsqlite3.so` in `/e`.

Later on, `my_executable` goes on to run a python interpreter. Eventually, a python `import` call tries to load `libsqlite3` and it gets resolved according to the `RPATH` from `my_executable`, and `ldd` throws an error about unresolved symbols.

Thankfully, in this specific case, I can just run `LD_DEBUG=libs python -c "import IPython"` to see what Python wants:

```
    396818:     find library=libsqlite3.so.0 [0]; searching
    396818:      search path=/home/me/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/../..             (RPATH from file /home/me/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/zlib.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
    396818:       trying file=/home/me/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/../../libsqlite3.so.0
```

So, `my_executable` and python want different versions of `libsqlite3`. First of all, is it possible to `dlopen` a second version of a shared library at runtime, and how do I tell `dlopen` to ignore the `RPATH` from `my_executable`?

Comment: perhaps try using `dlmopen`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First of all, is it possible to dlopen a second version of a shared library at runtime

Yes, *so long as* the two libraries differ in their `SONAME` (which they probably don't, but you can binary-patch one or both).

However, doing that is *really bad idea* -- the two libraries are exceedingly likely to define the same set of symbols, and the linux rules are that the first definition wins.

Doing this will *probably* cause very hard to debug crashes.

Effectively what's happened here is that you have two libraries with the same `SONAME`, but different ABI (we know the ABI's are different because if they weren't, you would not have gotten unresolved symbols -- it would all have just worked).

> and how do I tell dlopen to ignore the RPATH from my_executable

You can't. But you can `dlopen()` the other `libsqlite3.so.0` using absolute path (provided it has different `SONAME`).

---

Your best bet is *probably* to do what n.m. suggested: use `dlmopen` in your main program to load your version of `libsqlite3.so.0` into a separate loader namespace.